# after two sequential addToBackStack, supportFragmentManager.fragments size is one

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I have Main Activity with BottomNavigationView. in first tab of BottomNavigationView, I have a fragment. by click of user, I open two fragment in this way :

```
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right)
            .replace(R.id.mainFragmentContainer, FinancialFragment.newInstance(),"FinancialFragment")
            .addToBackStack("FinancialFragment")
            .commit()
```

with different tag. when user click on every bottomNaigation buttons, I pop all fragments from stack by this code :

```
   val fragments = supportFragmentManager.fragments
    val manager = supportFragmentManager
    val trans = manager.beginTransaction()
    var fragmentList = readFragmentsNameFromAssets()
    for (i in fragments.size - 1 downTo 0) {
        val fragment = fragments[i]
        if( fragment.tag ==fragmentList[0] || fragment.tag == fragmentList[1] || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[2] || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[3] || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[4] || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[5]
                || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[6] || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[7] || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[8] || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[9] || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[10] || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[11]
                || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[12] || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[13] || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[14] || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[15] || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[16]
                || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[17] || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[18] || fragment.tag ==fragmentList[19] ){
                trans.remove(fragment).commit()
                manager.popBackStack(fragment.tag, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
        }
    }
```

I have a problem : when I open two sequential fragment, supportFragmentManager.fragments size is one and seems the second fragment not added to stack and not pop so when I click on bottomNaigation button, just back to previous fragment.

Comment: Well you only start one transaction and who knows how many you are trying to commit